# RollupJS importing variables from ES6 modules that were never exported

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bundler, rollup

I have an ES6 module with 4 primitive values stored in `const` variables at the top of my file, along with a default function being exported. This function is imported into `main.js` and Rollup bundles it into a corresponding `dist/js` folder. When I look at the outputted file in `dist/js` I notice that Rollup has included the 4 variables:

module.js:

```
const x = 1,
      y = 2,
      z = 3, 
      a = 4;

export default function startTimer() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

---

main.js:

```
import startTimer from './path/to/module.js'
```

---

dist/js/main.js:

```
var x = 1,
    y = 2,
    z = 3,
    a = 4;

function startTimer() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

Why are the variables being imported? The function is in no way related to the variables or vice versa.

Thanks!

Comment: Because rollup doesn't tree-shake statements with side effects (like those assignments), only declarations. See https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/551

Comment: @bergi Thanks, I'm going to need to read more about side effect prevention in JS because It's still quite fuzzy for me.

Comment: What you are doing is not a side effect, it's just Rollup's fault not to recognise that (because in general it's really hard to do statically).